# Advice Needed for the Structure of Many-To-Many Fields in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

I am building a REST-API that will be consumed by an Angular application - this is for my guitar company’s website. There is an Artist Profile page that display an artist’s name, a short bio and a list of the projects(bands) they’re associated with and the date-ranges they were active with them. Here is where things get complicated.

Any given project can be associated with more than one artist - i.e. I could have two guitar players from the same band. I was able to solve that association by creating a many-to-many field and it worked great…until I realized that I have artists who have been in the same band at different times.

I have tried many approaches so far. I wish I could list them, but I kinda lost track. But, the code below is the where I am at right now. I can indeed associate a band with multiple artists, but I can’t associate different date ranges to different artists in the same bands. Any guidance is much appreciated.

```
class projectDate(models.Model):
    begin = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()


    def __str__(self):
        string_date_range = self.begin.strftime("%d/%m/%y") + "-" + self.end.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
        return  string_date_range

class artistProfiles(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    artist_image = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    band_website = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist_name


class artistProjects(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dates = models.ManyToManyField(projectDate, related_name='date_span')
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(artistProfiles, related_name='projects')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name



class artistSocialMedia(models.Model):
    facebook = models.URLField()
    twitter = models.URLField()
    instagram = models.URLField()
    artist = models.ForeignKey(artistProfiles, related_name='social_media', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist.artist_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@blhsing Ended up being the closest of all answers, but it took a little more massaging to get the relationships and JSON structure I was looking for.

Here is what worked for the models:
from django.db import models

```
class artistProfile(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    artist_image = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    band_website = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist_name

class artistProject(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name


class projectTenure(models.Model):
    begin = models.DateField()
    # blank and null are allowed here in case an artists is still with a given project
    end = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    project = models.ForeignKey(artistProject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(artistProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='projects')

    def __str__(self):
        #   TODO: find a way to return the related project and artist names
        string_date_range = self.begin.strftime("%d/%m/%y") + "-"
        return string_date_range


class artistSocialMedia(models.Model):
    facebook = models.URLField()
    twitter = models.URLField()
    instagram = models.URLField()
    artist = models.ForeignKey(artistProfile, related_name='social_media',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist.artist_name
```

And here is how I serialized it:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import (artistProfile, artistProject, projectTenure, artistSocialMedia)


class artistSocialMediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = artistSocialMedia
        fields = ('facebook', 'twitter', 'instagram')


class artistProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = artistProject
        fields = ('project_name',)


class projectTenureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project_name = serializers.CharField(source='project.project_name')

    class Meta:
        model = projectTenure
        fields = ('project_name', 'begin', 'end')


class artistProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projects = projectTenureSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    social_media = artistSocialMediaSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = artistProfile
        fields = ('artist_name', 'artist_image', 'description',
                  'band_website', 'projects', 'social_media')
```

Answer (score 1):

`artistProjects` and `projectDate` should not be a many-to-many relationship, since a `projectDate` is specific to a project and unlikely to be shared by many. You can instead make `artistProjects` a foreign key in `projectDate` so that a `artistProjects` can have many `projectDate`s but not vice versa:

```
class projectDate(models.Model):
    begin = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()
    project = models.ForeignKey(artistProjects, related_name='dates')
```

Note that your `artistProjects` represents just one project, so you should avoid giving it a plural name. Naming it `artistProject` will make your code more readable.

Comment: This seems to be pretty close to what I need, though I did need to  add a foreign key to `projectDate` that relates to the `artistProfile` model to make it show up in the Django Admin the way I expect/need. Now I need to serialize it and test it to see if it returns a JSON abject in the format I desire, with the correct behavior as far as each artist being able to have different active dates in the same band. I will report back Monday.

Comment: Also, you are correct that I used an incorrect naming convention for the model when I made it plural. I knew better, so who knows why I did it anyway. But, I did end up correcting that...good spot.

Comment: it took a bit more restructuring than I anticipated, but your answer did end up leading me down the correct path and I posted what ended up working as an answer, if you'd like to have a look. Thanks much!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether i can solve your problems or not. I am going to describe it in simple way so you can just adjust it with your models.
These is my advice. Hope it solve your problems.

```
Artist Profile
id (PK)
artist_name
artist_image
description
band_website

Artist Social Media
id (PK)
artist_profile_id (FK)(Artist Profile)
facebook
twitter
instagram

Artist Project
id (PK)
artist_band_project_id (FK)(Artis Band Project) 

Artist Band Project
id (PK)
begin
end

Artist Band Project Member
id (PK)
artis_band_project_id (FK)(Artist Band Project)
artis_profile_id (FK)(Artist Profile)
```

Regards,

Meikelwis Wijaya

Comment: It looks like your suggesting using a join table, or at least a Django-like version of one. This might work with some tweaks, but I think it may be a bit verbose. My original setup, as well as @blhsing's approach create the same effect with three models: `artistProfile` `artistProject` and `projectDate`.

Comment: Thanks @Meikelwis Wijaya, I ended up finding a way to get it working!